# Determine if a point is inside a cone generated by three vectors

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Assume three vectors
$$
\vec{A} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
a_x\\
a_y\\
a_z
\end{array}\right),
\vec{B} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
b_x\\
b_y\\
b_z
\end{array}\right),
\vec{C} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
c_x\\
c_y\\
c_z
\end{array}\right).
$$

How can I find if the point $(h_x,h_y,h_z)$ is inside the cone generated by these three vectors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the definition of cone generated by some vectors: $\vec H = (h_x, h_y, h_z)$ belongs to the cone generated by $\vec A$, $\vec B$ and $\vec C$ (I assume they are linearly independent) if and only if there are three *non-negative* real numbers $\lambda, \mu, \eta$ such that $$\vec H = \lambda \vec A + \mu \vec B + \eta  \vec C;$$ thus you have to solve the linear system given by the three equations (I assume $\vec A$, $\vec B$, $\vec C$, $\vec H$ are given) 
$$h_x = \lambda a_x + \mu b_x + \eta  c_x,$$
$$h_y = \lambda a_y + \mu b_y + \eta  c_y,$$
$$h_z = \lambda a_z + \mu b_z + \eta  c_z.$$

The solutions $\lambda, \mu, \eta$ are non-negative if and only if $\vec H$ belongs to the cone generated by $\vec A$, $\vec B$ and $\vec C$ (and they are all *strictly* positive iff $\vec H$ belongs to the interior of the cone).

Answer (score 2):

You could solve $\vec H=x\vec A+y\vec B+z\vec C$ for $x$, $y$ and
$z$ and see if these numbers are nonnegative.

Comment: Small note: if no solution exists, then $H$ is also not in the cone. If multiple solutions exist, it's in the cone if ONE of them has the nonnegative property.  (All this is only relevant if $A, B, C$ are not linearly independent, in which case the cone they span is somewhat degenerate.)